# Call of duty Black ops - not responding

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops

Whenever I turn this game on, it takes a lot of time to load, then it runs good. Suddenly all goes blank and it just says not responding. I got technical problem details here:

```
Problem Event Name: AppHangB1
Application Name:   BlackOps.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  4cd72fd8
Hang Signature: 9622
Hang Type:  2048
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Hang Signature 1:    96226ad693f2510a20319ec381dc4930
Additional Hang Signature 2:    2367
Additional Hang Signature 3:    236760d06080bf915ddfe8879ce5f11b
Additional Hang Signature 4:    9622
Additional Hang Signature 5:    96226ad693f2510a20319ec381dc4930
Additional Hang Signature 6:    2367
Additional Hang Signature 7:    236760d06080bf915ddfe8879ce5f11b
```

I can't understand anything out of it. I did update directx, display drivers, etc, but the problem persists. Another annoying thing is it takes lot of time to load.

System specifications are :

```
intel core i3 @2.2 Ghz
4-Gb ram
Windows 7-64 bit os.
intel HD 4000 built in graphics.
```

These meet required specifications, and also game runs smoothly till I get the above error.

Could any one solve this problem?

Comment: [Here post #52 got a solution](http://forums.evga.com/COD-Black-Ops-2-problem-FreezesNot-responding-FIXEDSOLVED-m1875767-p2.aspx) and [here's a different one](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1912671). Google got a lot of information on that kinda of error, seems common.

Comment: Black ops runs on integrated graphics? That sounds inaccurate

Comment: Will try to repost as a quality answer, but did just confirm black ops requires a dedicated graphic card. The card you detail is a basic default. These are generally not the best for any AAA title.